# ActiveRecord where method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, where-clause

I have a Model Sample with attribute car

car is a CSV with the different car names

```
x.car = "BMW,Ferrari,AUDI"
Sample.where(:car => "BMW")
```

returns [].

How can I use it as a like operator in SQL so that it returns x

Answer (score 1):

Use a condition like so in your where method (works just like prepared queries).

```
Sample.where("car LIKE ?", "BMW%")
```

More examples can be found in the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: great it works but now how can I club conditions on 2 different attributes

Comment: Sample.where("car LIKE ? AND id = ?", "BMW%", 2). OR, IN, etc work similarly